# How can I filter a stream with document ids?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

How can I filter the documents in the groups/collection with the document IDs in user/uid/usergroups  ?

I want to filter the groups/ with the document IDs that are stored in user/uid/usergroups to show the user only the Groups 
which are stored in his userprofile.

[image]
[image]

I don't get an error message with this Code but i don't see any Groups....

```
 Stream<QuerySnapshot> get userGroupIDs {
    return userGroupCollection.document(uid).collection('usergroups').snapshots();
  }

  Stream<QuerySnapshot> get group {
    return db.collection('groups').where('GroupID', isEqualTo: userGroupIDs).snapshots();
  }
```

.

```
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
                            stream: group,
                            builder: (BuildContext context,
                                AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
                              if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                                return new Text('Connecting...',style: TextStyle(fontSize: 200),);
                              } else {return ListView.builder(
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
  Stream<QuerySnapshot>  userGroupIDs() async*{
    String docId;
     Stream<QuerySnapshot> snap = Firestore.instance.collection("users").document("uid").collection('usergroups').snapshots();
     await for(var snapData in snap){
       snapData.documents.forEach((docResult){
        docId =  docResult.documentID;
       });
     }
   yield* Firestore.instance.collection('groups').where('GroupID', isEqualTo: docId).snapshots();
  }
```

Then inside `StreamBuilder`:

```
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
                            stream: userGroupIDs(),
```

First get the `documentID` from the collection `usergroups`, then use that id in the query with `GroupID`